# How to populate a cell in one sheet from a cell in the other using excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a row of cell to populate from one sheet in the same workbook to another.  I have sheet1 and sheet2.  They are text fields.  I did the formula =sheet1!A2. It works, but I get a 0 if there is not data in the copied cell (sheet1, A2).  How can I get the zero to be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=if(sheet1!A2="","",sheet1!A2)

This should evaluate the cell contents and keep blank cells as blank cells.  I assume you want cells with the number 0 in them to stay 0.

Comment: It did not work, it just put the formula in the cell. Any suggestions?

Comment: It did not work because it was a text cell.  After doing more research, sometimes a text formatted cell does this.

Comment: Just use the text-to-columns to make it general again and it will work.

Comment: this formula should work , it means that there are white spaces in the cell.so try this =IF(OR(Sheet1!A1="",Sheet1!A1=" "),"",Sheet1!A1)